# Use STL to populate a vector<T> from map<T,Z>'s keys

Tags: c++, stl

```
map<T,Z> m= ...;
vector<T> v;
v.reserve(m.size);
for(map<T,Z>::iterator it=m.begin();it!=m.end();++it)
{
 v.push_back(it->first);
}
```

Is there a nicer 1-line version using some STL function(s)?

**edit: *not* using c++11!**

Comment: Overkill? You are not typing too many lines of code to achieve this anyway.

Comment: @Als: by that logic much of std::algorithm is equally useless.

Comment: @Mahesh - I was thinking of some back-inserter magic, or something

Comment: You could use some sort of transform iterator, but I forget whether there's one in the standard library. Boost has one. Then you can construct `v` directly from a pair of iterators. Not sure if you'd end up with less typing, though :-)

Comment: @John:Not really, there is a difference between Optimization and Premature Optimization, Didn't say the Q is wrong, Just suggested it might be an overkill.

Comment: It's not for performance reasons, partly to avoid manually typing a loop and partly just curiosity. Although generally, using standard functionality on vector data is preferable to writing a loop because in future, who knows it might be parallelized or something cool.

Comment: @John: I don't know about copy operations because in c++ thats really complicated, but things like add are already paralleled in c++0x (if you use the right function).

Comment: Did you really mean the STL, or did you mean the C++ Standard Library?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Portable:

```
struct SelectKey {
  template <typename F, typename S>
  F operator()(const std::pair<const F, S> &x) const { return x.first; }
};

std::transform(m.cbegin(), m.cend(), std::back_inserter(v), SelectKey());
```

I think some implementations of STL have a non-standard extension called `select1st`, which is the equivalent of `SelectKey` shown here.  As K-Ballo pointed out in the comments, there's also a TR1 version.  I like the explicitly-named version as it's easier to see what's going on.

Since there's no need for state, you can get away with slightly less boilerplate by using an actual function rather than a functor:

```
template <typename F, typename S>
F SelectKey()(const std::pair<const F, S> &x) { return x.first; }

std::transform(m.cbegin(), m.cend(), std::back_inserter(v), SelectKey);
```

If you could use **C++11**, you could use a lambda, which keeps the selection code close to where it's used:

```
std::transform(m.cbegin(), m.cend(), std::back_inserter(v),
               [](const std::pair<const F, S> &x) { return x.first; });
```

or even range-based for-loop, which is probably the most elegant and readable:

```
for(const auto &x : m) {
  v.push_back(x.first);
}
```

Comment: What about lambda? it will be really one-liner then.

Comment: Your `operator()` ought to be `const`. In TR1 this could be achieved with `std::bind( &map< T, Z >::value_type::first, _1 )`.

Comment: Shouldn't templatize the struct, but rather the `operator()`. And if you really want to templatize the struct, you should provide arguments when creating it: `SelectKey<const T,V>()`.

Comment: All good comments.  I had a mention of lambda in my answer, but I must have deleted it by accident.

Comment: Does transform only accept functor objects, can't you pass a function directly? I'm sure I've seen it done but maybe that was non-standard, or my imagination :)

Comment: @John You can also pass a function, but you still have to define the function (as `first` is a variable), so you can also just use a functor, that can at least be defined locally.

Answer (score 4):

Pre C++11, you could use transform and a custom function struct:

```
template <class K, class V>
struct key_selector : std::unary_function<const std::pair<K, V>&, const K&>
{
    const K& operator()(const std::pair<K, V>& element) const
    {
        return element.first;
    }
};

transform(m.begin(), m.end(), back_inserter(v), key_selector<T,Z>());
```

If you have access to boost or TR1, you can replace `key_selector` with `mem_fn`

```
transform(m.begin(), m.end(), back_inserter(v), mem_fn(&map<T,Z>::value_type::first));
```

Post- C++11, you can use lambdas:

```
transform(m.begin(), m.end(), back_inserter(v), [](const map<T,Z>::value_type& x) {return x.first;});
```

Comment: In pre C++11 you could not use `bind`. If you rely on non-std extensions or boost, then say so.

Comment: @Christian : True, with the caveat that pre-C++11 you _could_ use `std::tr1::bind`.

Comment: @ildjarn Yes, but then he should say so and not pretend it to be standard.

Comment: Gah I've been using TR1 for so long I forgot it wasn't part of C++03. In C++03 you could use mem_fn or bind1st though, couldn't you? When I get a second I'll see if I can dig up the C++03 docs and fix my answer.

Comment: @Ayjay It won't work with `std::mem_fn`, because `std::pair`'s `first` member is not a function but a variable. Now I wonder if it even works with `tr1::bind`?

Comment: tr1's bind and mem_fn work with pointer-to-members. It seems that the mem_fun available pre-TR1 does not however. I think that writing a function object may be the only way pre-TR1. (How did we ever get anything done pre-TR1?!)

Answer (score 2):

In C++11, you can use lambda expressions:

```
typedef std::map< std::string, std::string > map_t;
map_t map;
std::vector< std::string > v;

std::for_each(map.begin(), map.end(), [&v](map_t::value_type const& it)
        {
            v.push_back(it.first);
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do something along the lines of:

```
std::transform(m.begin(), m.end(), std::back_inserter(v), FUNCTOR);
```

Where FUNCTOR depends on what version of the STL or libraries and compilers that you have.

C++11 (lambda)

```
std::transform(m.begin(), m.end(), std::back_inserter(v), [](map<T,Z>::const_reference a) { return a.first; });
```

C++11 (std::get)

```
std::transform(m.begin(), m.end(), std::back_inserter(v), &std::get<0>);
```

C++ SGI STL has a functor called select1st which can be used

```
std::transform(m.begin(), m.end(), std::back_inserter(v), select1st);
```

C++03 (Not C++11) using a functor object like other people have described.